# I can't access to my assets in Android studio Proyect

Tags: java, android-studio, inputstream, credentials, ioexception

I'm trying to connect my app to google drive using the driveAPI but I got an `IOException` when I tried to get the input stream of the credential path.

```
public Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);//getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);//MainActivity.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);

        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
        //returns an authorized Credential object.
        return credential;
    }
```

And this is the path:

```
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "CapturaVideo/app/src/main/assets/credentials.json";  // "credentials.json";`
```

Here is my project's file structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uRbq.png)

I was trying with diferent lines of instructions but I get the same error

```
//getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
//MainActivity.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
```

Answer (score 0):

- First

First of all, you have to check your `assets` folder. If it exists in your project navigate to `Proj-Name\app\src\main` and see if there have `assets` folder. And if it is available? check your **credentials.json** file is it exists? inside the folder. If not you have to create a `assets` folder.

- Second about your code snippet

According to your code snippet, You don't need to define their path! Only you need just specify their name **credentials.json**.

`getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("credentials.json")`

**TL;DR**

Sometimes. If you are using a room database and if you set `room.schemaLocation` to export their schemas. The project will automatically create an `assets` folder but it is not `assets`. Also, it will display on the Project sidebar. That is schemas folder. You can check it like this. Right-click that assets folder and navigate to open-in option go to explorer. (If it goes to **schemas** that's what I said.)

*-Hope you understand.*

*-Thank you!*